# If n and 6 are relatively prime numbers then prove that $n^2-1$ is divisible by 24

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I only proved that it's divisible by 12, I am missing another factor of 2.

Comment: Could you show your work thus far?

Comment: How did you prove that it's divisible by $12$?

Comment: Hint: Out of two consecutive even numbers, one must be divisible by $4$.

Answer (score 6):

If $n$ is relatively prime to $6$, then $n \equiv 1 \mod{6}$ or $n \equiv 5 \mod{6}$. If $n = 6k + 1$ for some $k$, then

$$n^2 - 1 = 36 k^2 + 12 k = 12 k (3k + 1)$$

If $k$ is even, the result is clear; if $k$ is odd, then $3k + 1$ is even and the result follows.

A similar argument works for when $n = 6k + 5$.

Comment: One can just write $n=\pm 1 \mod 6$, that is $n=6k\pm 1$.

Answer (score 2):

It is clear that $n^2\equiv 1 \mod{3}$, because of $(n,3)=1$ and Fermat theorem.  Also because $n$ is odd one can see that $n^2 \equiv 1 \mod{8}$ which finishes your proof. (Indeed either $n-1$ or $n+1$ is divisible by 4 and the other by 2).

Answer (score 1):

$$n^2-1=(n+1)(n-1)$$
$\gcd(n,6)=1$ implies

- $3\nmid n$, so surely $3$ divides one of the factors.
- $2\nmid n$, so $n$ is odd and both factors are even. Also, from two consecutive even numbers, there is one divisible by $4$, so we have $2\cdot 4=8$ as a factor.